# v-edit-dialog inside v-data-table restores original value when closed

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js

I have a Vue application that is using Vuetify. For some reason the `v-chip` component is not re-rendering when the binded value is changed.

```html
<v-data-table>
  <template v-slot:item.active="{ item }">
    <v-edit-dialog :return-value.sync="item.active">
      <v-chip :key="item.active" outlined :color="item.active ? 'success' : 'error'">{{ item.active ? "Open" : "Closed" }}</v-chip>
      <template v-slot:input>
        <v-switch
          @change="saveRowField(item.id, 'active', item.active)"
          v-model="item.active"
          :true-value="1" :false-value="0"
          color="success" label="Open"
          ></v-switch>
      </template>
    </v-edit-dialog>
  </template>
</v-data-table>
```

The `v-switch` in the `v-edit-dialog` correctly updates the binded field `item.active`. However the `v-chip` component inside the template does not rerender on state change.

The `:key` attribute is binded to the same field as the `v-switch`.

Why is the v-chip not re-rendering when the value binded to the key is changed?

Comment: Why do you have `:key` on `v-chip` ? It's not needed

Comment: It's a technique to force update

Comment: @DavidGo well....no, it's not

Comment: https://michaelnthiessen.com/force-re-render/

Comment: @DavidGo Well, still no. It's **hint** for Vue whether it can reuse existing component instances or not. It's useful if you need to trigger lifecycle hooks. If you using it "to force component re-render", it's just a "poor man's" workaround to some other reactivity issue in your component...

Comment: Yeah, I'm not saying that it's the main point of key. Just in this case it's used as a reaktivity hack. About "poor man's" well you need it sometimes when you working with third party solutions for example, I don't know a better way

Comment: OK, I see your point. I'v just seen so many people misuse it instead of trying to solve their real problem, I'm a bit allergic to it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tried your code and re-rendering content of `v-chip` is not an issue. What I see is chip is changed once I click `v-switch` but when `v-edit-dialog` is closed, the original value is restored.

So the problem is in `v-edit-dialog`. If you put `large` prop on it, it will display buttons - "Save" and "Cancel". If you use "Save" button, the value is saved. If "Cancel", original value is restored.

Without buttons, only way to close the dialog is clicking "away", which is interpreted as "Cancel" by `v-edit-dialog` and thus original value is restored...

Possible solutions:

1. Either let user use "Save"/"Cancel" buttons to confirm/cancel editing
2. Or remove `:return-value.sync="item.active"` (responsible for this Save/Cancel behavior).

[Demo](https://codepen.io/liwoj/pen/XWKJggm?editors=1010)